# Class not found exception for AsyncDatastoreService

Tags: google-app-engine

I've tried searching the web but I can't seem to find the cause of this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreService
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:176)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 98 more
```

It's really weird since I can properly run Junit test that access Datastore and Blobstore API. Only that when I run the app, this error shows.